# 'Expected primary-expression before string constant' error message on C++

Tags: c++

I've just gotten started with coding, with a Robotics class, and I have to make a code on C++ that reads integer user inputs in the serial monitor, puts them into an array and compares than in order to print the biggest one of them. Fairly simple, but hard for a newbie. The code uses a library function called SerialReadPrint that the teacher made for us, which reads the input in the serial monitor and converts it into a value, and one called findMax, which compares integers given. This is the code:

```
#include <SerialReadPrint.h> 
SerialReadPrint Function;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int number;
  int arraySize;
  int myArray[arraySize];
  int i;
  int max;
  int arrayElement;
  Function.s_read(String "How many numbers do you want?"){
    return number;
  }
  int arraySize=number;
  for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
  {
   Function.s_read(String "Enter the numbers please"){
    return arrayElement;
   }
   myArray[i]=arrayElement;
  }
   for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
   int max = findMax(int arraySize);
}
}

void loop()
{
}
```

However, on the second "Function.s_read" I recieve the following error message trying to compile:
expected primary-expression before string constant
How do I fix it?

Comment: Side note: `int myArray[arraySize];` is UB since `arraySize` is uninitialized.

Comment: Remove the `String` from inside the parameters, it doesn't belong there

Comment: I don't know why you don't get an error on the first `s_read` too, but what you want is `number = Function.s_read("How many numbers do you want?");`. However, I strongly suggest you study your text books again as you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to call functions.

Comment: Arduino I'm guessing

Comment: Nvm...not sure what this is. What are you using? What is "SerialReadPrint.h"

Comment: This is Arduino. SerialReadPrint.h is a function the teacher made for us told us to download to the library. I just realized I was only seeing the last error that showed up, but I had many more. I'm trying to use your suggestions and I think the amount of error messages is shortening. Sadly, I don't have a textbook to study with, or else I would, but I changed the way I'm calling the functions and I think it works better now. Still doesn't work completely (or partially, or minimally, I suck at this lol) though.